# Adding values onto unstacked bar chart - python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, charts, enumerate

Here is my code for a stacked bar chart. I can add percentage values for the first segment (AA), but how I can add values for all 4 segments?

[image: stacked bar chart with first segment value]

```
df = pd.read_csv("123.csv")

df1 = df.groupby(['Country', 'ClassWeight']) 
['Count'].sum().unstack('ClassWeight').fillna(0)

#sort on the 'total' column, and then drop it to avoid double plotting

ax = df1.sort_values(['total']).iloc[:,:-1].plot(kind='barh', width=0.8, 
stacked=True, figsize=(15, 10),colormap=ListedColormap(sns.color_palette("Blues_d")))

#plot barchart
ax.set_xlabel('No.of Shipments',fontsize=15)

ax.set_ylabel('Country',fontsize=15)

plt.xticks(fontsize=15)

plt.yticks(fontsize=15)

plt.title('Total Shipments by Country and Customer Class',fontsize=15)

df2=df1.sort_values(['total'],ascending=True)

df2['AA'] = 100*df2['AA']/df2['total']

df2['A'] = 100*df2['A']/df2['total']

df2['B'] = 100*df2['B']/df2['total']

df2['C'] = 100*df2['C']/df2['total']

df3 = df2.iloc[:,:-1]

#Can only enumerate on the AA column. How could we do all 4 columns?

for i, v in enumerate(df3['AA']):
    ax.text(v + -1, i + -0.2, str("{0:.1f}%".format(v)), color='white', 
fontweight='bold', fontsize=15)
```

Example data:

```
ClassWeight            AA          A          B          C
Country                                                   
Romania         17.142857  32.268908  28.235294  22.352941
Finland         60.325203  13.495935  12.682927  13.495935
```

{'Country': {0: 'France', 1: 'Poland', 2: 'Lithuania', 3: 'United Kingdom', 4: 'Denmark'}, 'Count': {0: 233, 1: 232, 2: 286, 3: 236, 4: 223}, 'SumWeight': {0: 8072469.5, 1: 6689511.05, 2: 5158305.25, 3: 4675914.53, 4: 3536684.52}, 'AvgWeight': {0: 34645.79, 1: 28834.1, 2: 18036.03, 3: 19813.2, 4: 15859.57}, 'ClassWeight': {0: 'AA', 1: 'AA', 2: 'AA', 3: 'AA', 4: 'AA'}}

Comment: Can you edit some of your example data into your post as text, rather than an image? It makes it much easier for people to use.

Comment: Thanks for the edit

Comment: Which frame does your example data represent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried to rearrange your code a bit - you don't need to create new dataframes each time, and you only really need to sort by your totals once.

```
import pandas as pd

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Country': {0: 'France', 1: 'France', 2: 'France', 3: 'France', 4: 'France'},
     'Count': {0: 100, 1: 232, 2: 286, 3: 236, 4: 854},
     'ClassWeight': {0: 'AA', 1: 'A', 2: 'B', 3: 'C', 4: 'total'}}
)

# Track which value columns we want to plot
VALUE_COLS =['AA', 'A', 'B', 'C']

# We only need to sort_values once, so we might as well do it as we generate df1
df1 = df.groupby(['Country', 'ClassWeight'])['Count']\
        .sum()\
        .unstack('ClassWeight')\
        .fillna(0)\
        .sort_values(by='total', ascending=False)

# Get percentage values 
for col in VALUE_COLS:
    df1[col + '_%'] = 100*df1[col]/df1['total']

ax = df1[VALUE_COLS].plot(kind='barh', width=0.8,stacked=True,
                          figsize=(15, 10),
                          colormap=ListedColormap(sns.color_palette("Blues_d")))

# Set up labels and ticks
ax.set_xlabel('No.of Shipments',fontsize=15)
ax.set_ylabel('Country',fontsize=15)
plt.xticks(fontsize=15)
plt.yticks(fontsize=15)
plt.title('Total Shipments by Country and Customer Class',fontsize=15)

# Add in text labels
df1['label_tot'] = 0
for col in VALUE_COLS:
    df1['label_tot'] += df1[col]
    for i, (val, pos) in enumerate(df1[[col + '_%', 'label_tot']].itertuples(index=False, name=None)):
        ax.text(pos + -1, i, str("{0:.1f}%".format(val)),
                color='white',fontweight='bold', fontsize=15, ha='right')
```

With my slightly modified version of your input data, this gives something like:

[image]

Comment: That code works for printing the values for the 4 columns, but they are all on top of each other. How would I then spread them across each stack bar?

Comment: That ax.text is plotting the 4 values at the same point for each country

Comment: You're right - I've edited to try and track a running total. It'd be helpful if you could explain what the provided data corresponds to so I can run through your code and check this works.

Comment: I get the following error on the line ax.text  ---> TypeError: must be str, not int. The columns are the type of customer, and the values are percentage breakdowns over the 4 columns for each country. Apologies, it is my first time using this site and so I'm not yet aware of what info I am expected to include.

Comment: If you can do `print(df.head(5).to_dict())` and then edit the result of that into your post? That would let me know what data you're working with from the start